# Displaying data from database in ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I have this code in android that prints data from database to log.

```
List<Message> messages = db.getAllMessages();

for (Message mg : messages) 
{
  String log = "Id: "+mg.getID()+", Message: " + mg.getMessage() + ", Time: " + mg.getDate();
  // display everything on log
  Log.d("", log);
}
```

How do I display it in a ListView instead of printing to log ?

Comment: Hold these values in a pojo class and pass the object of pojo class to List's adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a list that you would store your values in if not already. For example:

```
private ArrayList<String> YOUR_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, use this in an array adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, YOUR_LIST);
```

Finally, set your adapter:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LISTVIEW);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What *you* could do in your example, is something like this:

```
List<Message> messages = db.getAllMessages();
ArrayList<String> YOUR_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

for (Message mg : messages) {
    String log = "Id: " + mg.getID() + ", Message: " + mg.getMessage() + ", Time: " + mg.getDate();
    YOUR_LIST.add(log);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, YOUR_LIST);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LISTVIEW);
listView.setAdapter(adapter)
```